# How to checkout a previous commit with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I'm on r1594 and want to checkout r1490, with `git` I would do something like:

```
git checkout 1490
```

How do I do this with TortoiseSVN? or `svn` cmd line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the desired revision in the Checkout dialog.
[image]

---

If you already have a working copy, select *Update to revision* from the context menu.
[image]

Comment: Ah sweet, idk how I missed "Update to revision"